# Book on quadric surfaces with linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

Most information that I can find about quadric surfaces is written from a calculus perspective - without using any matrices or vectors. However, I would like to have a reference that tells me the different representations for a quadric surface and also some background on why these representations are used. So, e.g., I want to see both the vector representation(s) and the scalar representation(s) of a cone. Are there any books that cover this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a copy, have a look at: "Solid Analytical Geometry and Determinants" by Arnold Dresden, c.1930, published by John Wiley and Sons. I have a copy of the Fourth Printing, 1948. (No ISBN in my copy.)

Comment: Thanks - I found a digital version at archive.org:
http://archive.org/details/solidanalyticalg031938mbp